# jquery call function fore multiple elements change

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html something like:

```
<html>
    ...
    <select class="ra1" id="rate2620_"> ... </select>
    <select class="ra1" id="rate2621_"> ... </select>
    ...
</html>
```

I have a for that is generating me all the functions for every select like:

```
for (i=from; i> to; i--){
    var ii = i.toString(); // ii = 2621 or 2620 or ...
    $("#rate" + i + "_").live("change", {pos: ii} ,function(e){
        sendValue($(this).val(),e.data.pos);
    });
}
```

I want to change my code to a function that acts for class="ra1"
Something like (not working) :

```
$('.ra1').live("change", function(e){

    var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id"); // get the id element
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');  // convert from id="rate2620_" to> id="2620"

    sendValue($(this).val(),id);
});
```

So {pos: ii} ii should be changed with id, but I really have no ideea how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong id selector. It should be:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");//or this.id for pure JS
```

also live has been deprecated in jquery 1.7+. If you are using later versions then use jquery `.on()`

Comment: `this.id` also do that and i would say it is better to use.

Comment: @Jai: yup. the idea was him being using wrong id selector. Thanks :)